# Using is home to get content

Tags: php, theme-development

I'm looking to use `is_home` to 'get content' as I would like my blog page to echo a header, content and date/time but I only want all other pages to get the content.

This is what i have so far...

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>
    <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>

} else {

    <p><?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?></p>

}
?>
```

I currently get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' on line 7

Any help with how to code this right and a short explanation would be great.

Thanks in advance!

For any future noobies like me... this did the job:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<? if ( is_home() ): ?>
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
  <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
  <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
<? else: ?>
  <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Then what output you are getting ?

Comment: Sorry this is my first time attempting to create a theme -  I'm trying to have my 'post page' have the post header, content and date/time but i want all other pages to just show the content. I could be going around this the wrong way but i've figured out that 'is home' only targets the 'post page'... hope that makes sense!

Comment: you have some basic php syntax errors with closing / opening php properly. do you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: @DannyBoy WordPress say ~ _Important: Never use shorthand PHP start tags. Always use full PHP tags._ WordPress have PHP Coding Standars, you can learn more https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#no-shorthand-php-tags

Comment: Will keep that in mind. Thanks for the tip Jevuska.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to either close your php tags before regular html. Or you need to use php to print the html for you.

Comment: Thanks, first time with PHP so although this is basic your help is much appreciated

Comment: Is there a cleaner version of the above code i've added?

Comment: Seems ok. As @Jevuska said in another comment, that you probably shouldn't be using shorthand code for php tags such as <? and <?= and instead fully write out <?php and <?php echo. This is due to not all servers having a full support for this.

Also I would not use h4 tag for the post date as i would consider it bad practice to skip tiers, and doing so would require the "content" to always at least have h2 and h3.

In addition, I'm not fully sure of how the rest of your setup goes, but it seems that unless it's home you're not printing out h1. All pages should have one h1 tag, one and no more.